# how to use "not equal to" in where condition using linq with entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

how to use "not equal to" in where condition using LINQ with entity framework.

```
public ActionResult ViewOfficeType()
{            
   return View(entity.TBL_OFFICETYPE.Where(p => p.STATUS<>"D").ToList());
}
```

> it shows invalid expression '>'

if i use '!='.It doesn't show error.But it doesn't work.

Comment: != will work, you need to use the correct data

Comment: if you want to ignore the case then, use `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` inside the `Equals` method. In C# code `<>` is not the correct operator

Comment: *doesn't work* -- Please be more specific. You accepted an answer that uses `Contains`. I'm not convinced that it's the right solution, "not Contains" isn't the same as "not equal to".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var status = entity.TBL_OFFICETYPE.Select(p => p.STATUS == "D");
           return View(entity.TBL_OFFICETYPE.Where(p => !status.Contains(p.STATUS == "D")).ToList());
```

plz try this

Answer (score 3):

you can use the `!` operator on `Equals()`

```
public ActionResult ViewOfficeType()
{            
    return View(entity.TBL_OFFICETYPE.Where(p => !p.Equals("D")).ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can you use the following approaches

1. Use != operator in you lambda expression

```js
public ActionResult ViewOfficeType()
{            
   return View(entity.TBL_OFFICETYPE.Where(p => p.STATUS != "D").ToList());
}
```

2. Use !string.Equals

```js
public ActionResult ViewOfficeType()
{            
   return View(entity.TBL_OFFICETYPE.Where(p => !p.STATUS.Equals("D")).ToList());
}
```

Note: Be aware of string comparison issues like character encoding, and case sensitivity etc.

Comment: It doesn't display any record

Comment: Maybe it does not match criteria for any record in your database. Otherwise, technically both of the above approaches are correct.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer a Extension method as follows:

```
public static class StringExtension
{
    public static bool NotEquals(this string source, string target)
    {
        return !(source.Equals(target));        
    }
}
```

How it works:

```
   string source = "Test"; // Sample / Source data
```

// Tested with "test", result is true, since the case is different, so two strings are different

```
   source.NotEquals("test");
```

// Tested with "Test", result is false, since they are same

```
   source.NotEquals("Test");
```

Lot more things are possible inside the extension method, based on whether you want to ignore the case, you can simply pass `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` in the Equals method, then "Test" will be evaluated equal to "test" (case ignored)